# Is There A Built-in Way to Filter with Given Function in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, filter

I especially wonder if I can use map, filter and reduce functions with Django model instances. If I cannot, is there a built-in way to pass a function to filter querying in Django?

Let me demonstrate my real problem for better understanding. I use PostgreSQL to use ArrayField and I have similiar model as below:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    stops_forwards = ArrayField(
    ArrayField(
        models.PositiveIntegerField(),
        size=2
    ),
    default=[],
    verbose_name="Stops Forwards (Ordered)"
    )

    stops_backwards = ArrayField(
    ArrayField(
        models.PositiveIntegerField(),
        size=2
    ),
    default=[],
    verbose_name="Stops Backwards (Ordered)"
    )
```

As you can see above, I have embedded ArrayFields inside `stops_forwards` and `stops_backwards`. I use embedded ones  so as to keep it in order. An example data is shown as below:

```
[
    [1, 35],
    [2, 40],
    [3, 180],
    [4, 285]
    # ... and it goes
]
```

What I want to do is to check if a particular stop id (like `285`) is in embedded ArrayField. Assuming that I have a function called `has_route_stop` that I do not know how it works but I call it as below:

```
filter(lambda: has_route_stop(285), instances)
```

Or, is there a built-in way in Django API to do this?

---

## Environment

- Python 3.5.1
- Django 1.9.9
- PostgreSQL 9.5.4
- psycopg2 2.6.2

Comment: "Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements."

Comment: Yes, it is a better solution. However, a custom script I've written somehow mixes the order of data (or shuffles it when Django queries, I do not know). So I thought it is a better solution to keep them with their orders as integer. But I will look whatever I can do to avoid using embedded arrays. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django's Postgres integration allows you to query in embedded arrays using the `__contains` operator. So you can do:

```
Route.objects.filter(stops_forwards__contains=[285])
```

See [the ArrayField documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield).